# Protocol declaration in Swift - Xcode 6 beta 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6-beta5

With **Xcode 6 beta 5** protocol and delegate doesn't work like first. **printCar()** is not invoked when **self.delegate?.printCar()** it's called. How can I use protocol & delegate now?

```
import UIKit

protocol communication{
    func printCar()
}

class car{
    var delegate:communication?

    init(){}

    func passCar(){
        self.delegate?.printCar()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,communication {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("start")
        var bmw = car()
        bmw.passCar()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func printCar(){
        println("car")
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.delegate` is `nil` when `init()` is called. - (In fact you nowhere set the delegate to the view controller class.)

Comment: I wrote a bad example, I try to rewrite it

Comment: My last remark still applies (also in the answer below): You don't assign a delegate (such as `bmw.delegate = self`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the car's `delegate` property, so there's no object to call `printCar()` on.

Also, it's convention to use initial caps for type names in Swift. (You'll notice that it's such strong convention that even SO's syntax highlighter expects it.)

BTW, it has nothing to do with this issue, but you might want to be on Xcode 6 beta 6 by now.

Another unrelated issue: Your car class's `delegate` property should probably be marked as `weak`. Otherwise, if the car's delegate is the object that owns the car, you get a memory leak.

Comment: Before you call `bmw.passCar()`, you need to assign something to `bmw`'s `delegate` property. Otherwise the `self.delegate?.printCar()` call in that method won't execute, because `self.delegate?` resolves to `nil`.